# GoDaddy 4GH Hosting Experiences?

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, godaddy, cloud-hosting, sql-server

I've just come across [GoDaddy's 4GH Hosting](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx). It's incredibly cheap and the sales blurb makes it sound amazing.

Anyone tried it out yet (particularly for ASP.NET / MS SQL Server sites)? I'd love to hear your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried there 4GH hosting, but I will say this. I tried to use Godaddy before for an ASP.net application and my experience was really poor. By default your application security level is set to low which makes your task to create a pretty awesome site pretty much impossible and it's like pulling teeth trying to get them to bump you up to a medium or high security level. And then you have their friendly error messages which give you no information regarding the bug you are experiencing. I would recommend using a hosting provider that specializes in Microsoft based technologies.

Comment: Thanks for that Jeremy... actually, as I started to search for reviews I started to realize that GoDaddy has a very bad track record. Seems you're only ok if you're hosting static content.